# Localdb 2014 SP1 error on Win 7

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, localdb

LocalDb 2014 works well on win 10 but I get error on win 7 when I want to connect to `.mdf` in my app (on Win 7):

> sql network interfaces error 26

[image: error26 screen shot]

and when I want to start `sqlservr.exe`, I get this error

[image]

My connection string is :

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFileName=mydbaddress.mdf;Initial Catalog=mydbname;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False
```

Comment: You should never connect to the mdf file you usually will get a credential error unless you are an admin.  Just connect t the server with the database name.  See www.connectionstrings.com.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using wrong Connection String

Use

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v12.0;AttachDbFileName=mydbaddress.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False
```

1. DO not use `Initial Catalog` and `AttachDBFileName` in same connectionString.
2. `v12.0` is used for `LocalDB 2014` and `v11.0` is used for `LocalDB 2012`. Use respectively.

Comment: thanks . but v12 not work on localdb2014 . i test it again